# HTML or URL Escaping for an IMG tag?

Tags: html, xml, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I have an img src url which looks like

> https://example.com/bar.png?queryA=https://example.com/blah&queryB=1

How should I apply HTML or URL escaping/encoding when adding this to an img HTML tag?

```
<img src="https://example.com/bar.png?queryA=https://example.com/blah&queryB=1" alt="Foo" width="500" height="600">
```

Would it be a combination of both? What would the final img src look like?

Answer (score 0):

well it is just a string, that is matched against the local resources and if not found sent through a GET method. Then it is up to the other server to send you an image back. No escape needed